# pyinstaller kivy error Unable to get any Image provider, abort

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, virtualenv, pyinstaller

hi i create a `kivy python` with **`pyinstaller`** in `virtualenv`

my program run in console with command `python cipol.py` is run successfully wihout no error
but when create exe with pyinstaller with command `pyinstaller cipol.spec`

it will return

[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 186 symbols loaded

[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers:  (img_tex, img_dds, img_ffpyplayer, img_pil, img_sdl2 ignored)

[CRITICAL] [App         ] Unable to get any Image provider, abort.

this is my spec file:

```
# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-
from kivy_deps import sdl2, glew
import os
os.environ['KIVY_IMAGE'] = 'pil,sdl2'
from importlib import __import__

block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(['C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\cipol-kivy\\exe\\venv\\Lib\\sync\\cipol.py'],
         pathex=['C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\cipol-kivy\\exe\\venv\\Lib\\sync'],
         binaries=[],
         datas=[],
         hiddenimports=['win32file','win32timezone'],
         hookspath=[],
         runtime_hooks=[],
         excludes=[],
         win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
         win_private_assemblies=False,
         cipher=block_cipher,
         noarchive=False)
a.datas += [('logo.png','C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\cipol-kivy\\exe\\venv\\Lib\\sync\\logo.png','DATA'), ('style.kv', 'C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\cipol-kivy\\exe\\venv\\Lib\\sync\\style.kv', 'DATA')]

pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
         cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
      a.scripts,
      [],
      exclude_binaries=True,
      name='cipolsync',
      debug=True,
      bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
      strip=False,
      upx=True,
      console=True,
      icon='C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\cipol-kivy\\exe\\venv\\Lib\\sync\\cipol.ico')
coll = COLLECT(exe,
            Tree('C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\cipol-kivy\\exe\\venv\\Lib\\sync\\'),
           a.binaries,
           a.zipfiles,
           a.datas,
           *[Tree(p) for p in (sdl2.dep_bins + glew.dep_bins)],
           strip=False,
           upx=True,
           upx_exclude=[],
           name='cipolsync')
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using this command: `pyinsaller --onefile cipol.py`. Then delete all folders and spec file but don't delete the dist folder. The exe file will be inside of that dist folder.

Comment: tried this but return prev error didn't solve error